# How to merge two lists in repository?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I've got this ApiInterface file with several API calls :

```
interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("wp/v2/mec-events?per_page=50")
    fun getData(): Call<List<MyDataItem>>

    @GET("wp/v2/mec_location?per_page=50")
    fun getPlaces(): Call<List<PlacesItem>>

    @GET("wp/v2/mec_category?per_page=50")
    fun getCat(): Call<List<CatItem>>





    companion object{
        var retrofitService: ApiInterface? = null


        fun getInstance() : ApiInterface{

            val gson = GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").create()
            val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
                .create(ApiInterface::class.java)

            return retrofitBuilder
        }


    }


}
```

A Repository file :

```
class MainDataRepository(
    private val retrofitService: ApiInterface,

    ) {
    fun getData() = retrofitService.getData()
    fun getPlaces() = retrofitService.getPlaces()
    fun getCat() = retrofitService.getCat()

}
```

And a ViewModel :

```
class MainDataViewModel constructor(private val repository: MainDataRepository)  : ViewModel() {

    val dataList = MutableLiveData<List<MyDataItem>>()
    val errorMessage = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun getData() {

        val response = repository.getData()
        response.enqueue(object : Callback<List<MyDataItem>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>>, response: Response<List<MyDataItem>>) {
                dataList.postValue(response.body())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>>, t: Throwable) {
                errorMessage.postValue(t.message)
            }
        })
    }

    val placesList = MutableLiveData<List<PlacesItem>>()


    fun getPlaces(){
        val response = repository.getPlaces()
        response.enqueue(object : Callback<List<PlacesItem>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<PlacesItem>>, response: Response<List<PlacesItem>>) {
                placesList.postValue(response.body())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<PlacesItem>>, t: Throwable) {
                errorMessage.postValue(t.message)
            }
        })
    }

    val catList = MutableLiveData<List<CatItem>>()

    fun getCat() {

        val response = repository.getCat()
        response.enqueue(object : Callback<List<CatItem>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<CatItem>>, response: Response<List<CatItem>>) {
                catList.postValue(response.body())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<CatItem>>, t: Throwable) {
                errorMessage.postValue(t.message)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

My Data lists :

```
data class MyDataItem(
    val id: Int,
    val content: Content,
    val startdate : String,
    val featured_media: Int,
    val mec_category: List<String>,
    val title: Title,
    val cost : String,
    val starthours : String,
    val endhours : String,
    val places : List<String>,
    val excerpt : Excerpt,
    val link : String

    ) {}

class CatItem(
    val id : Int,
    val count : Int,
    val name : String,
) {}
class PlacesItem(
    val id : Int,
    val count : Int,
    val name : String
) {}
```

I can't figure out how to merge these lists in order to have something like this (with the names of categories and places within the main list) :

```
class NewList(
    val id: Int,
    val content: Content,
    val startdate : String,
    val featured_media: Int,
    val mec_category: List<String>,
    val mec_category_name : String,
    val title: Title,
    val cost : String,
    val starthours : String,
    val endhours : String,
    val places : List<String>,
    val places_name : String,
    val excerpt : Excerpt,
    val link : String

    ) {}
```

the JSON looks like this :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1390,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "MY TITLE"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "MY CONTENT",
      "protected": false
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "MY EXCERPT",
      "protected": false
    },
    "mec_category": [52],
    "startdate": "2021-12-11",
    "starthours": "2",
    "endhours": "4",
    "cost": "0",
    "places": ["24"],  
  },
...]

[{
    "id": 24,
    "count": 1,
    "name": "PLACES NAME",
  },
...]

[{
    "id": 52,
    "count": 3,
    "name": "CATEGORY NAME",
  },
...]
```

I've tried to map two lists together but this doesn't work : I can't fetch the value of the 'mec_category' or 'places' because its a list format...
Any clue to help ?

Comment: Why are _mec_category_ and _places_ lists? Can there be multiple values for these in the JSON?

Comment: Or to put it in other words: shouldn't _mec_category_name_ and _places_name_ not also be plural and be of type of List<String>?

Comment: MyData can have several places and several mec_category if  I understand your question 